# What type of password I have to give to set the custom account for application pool identity

Tags: iis-7

I'm trying to set the Identity of the Application Pool to a specific account. When I'm entering the password for a user name it says

**The specified password is invalid.Type a new password.**

Is there any specific requirement for the password field?

Comment: I actually have an opposite problem. Using `appcmd.exe set config` I get to set domain\username and password even when they are wrong? Why does that happen?

Answer (score 64):

For me, it was that I wasn't adding the domain name to the login (DOMAIN\USER). It was defaulting to a local account

Comment: That was the issue for me as well :) Sometimes we may forget some too basic things. Ha ha :)

Answer (score 16):

I'd configured the settings below but I was still getting the same error when trying to change the identity of the new application pool using the UI:

'The specified password is invalid.  Type a new password.'

- Local Users and Groups

  - Added the Domain Service Account to the local group 'IIS_IUSRS'.
- Local Security Policy

  - Added the domain service account to the policies:

    - Access this computer from the network
    - Deny log on locally
    - Log on as a batch job
    - Log on as a service

The method that worked for me was to ditch the UI and do it via the command line using appcmd.exe.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.userName:DOMAIN\USER_NAME /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.password:PASSWORD
```

This method is described in the article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: This helped me though I used this article: [link](https://itgala.xyz/iis-error-the-specified-password-is-invalid-type-a-new-password/)

Comment: This was the only method that worked for me trying to follow Configure IIS 7 for Web Synchronization

Answer (score 15):

The user account you specify must have "Access this computer from the network" user right in group policy.

If this is server is joined to a domain, will need to add this right via Group Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment.

Comment: Also check that the user (or a group the user is a member of) does not have the "Deny access to this computer from the network" policy applied.

Answer (score 11):

For me it was because I didn't mention the domain name as part of the user name

Comment: YES. `DOMAINNAME\username` and it was fixed. What a terrible error message that doesn't help at all

Answer (score 8):

Another common cause for this error is long usernames...  if you continue to be baffled (as I was), try using the "Pre-Windows 2000" version of the username, as listed in AD (assuming you're using a domain account).  Worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

It might also mean that the account is *Locked Out* (too many failed login attempts before), which you can configure in the Local Users and Groups MMC.

Comment: This is true.  It's also very unfortunate, as in my case the person who unlocks the accounts is not myself, so I have to send many e-mails about it, and am never quite sure if this also is a problem.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. It baffled me as the message says there is something wrong with the password. It turned out that the account I was trying to use did not have logon rights on the IIS Server. I added the account to the local Administrators group to resolve the issue - if that's not an option then we have to somehow give the account logon rights to the computer.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I faced this issue today and  resolved the same way you mentioned.

Comment: I actually have an opposite problem. Using `appcmd.exe set config` I get to set domain\username and password even when they are wrong? Why does that happen

Answer (score 2):

The standard windows password rules in the security manager do apply. I believe you have to use an existing account, and that users assigned password. If the security manager was configured after the user account was setup, and the password does not expire, then they may have weaker password rules than the currently existing ones which could create a conflict.

In server 2008R2 %windir%\system32\secpol.msc /s should bring up the local security policy
Not sure if its the same in other OS versions.

Comment: I'm giving the existing user name and password associated to that user name only. Still getting password is invalid message. What is security manager? Mine is Windows 2008 Enterprise.

Comment: I have the same problem and the solution is to use an existing account and the user assigned password. It is the account and password you set when you create the user in Computer Management. Using other arbitrary password won't work.

Comment: I actually have an opposite problem. Using `appcmd.exe set config` I get to set domain\username and password even when they are wrong? Why does that happen

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue and solved with typing username which following domain name. As the pic shown. And entered the windows login password then it works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO0Ab.png)

Answer (score 2):

Getting Error -
**The specified password is invalid.Type a new password.**

Use the below command from the CMD and it will fix the issue-

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.userName:DOMAIN\USER_NAME /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.password:PASSWORD
```

Comment: You may quote the script using Ctrl+K

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was that the domain user had to be a member of the IIS_IUSRS group.  Added the user to the group via Computer Management -> Users and Groups, restarted the app pool and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it must be a local account on IIS server, rather than a domain account.

Comment: I am a software developer, in our shop we also have one set of IT admins and another set of SQL admins.  Eventually, an IT admin was able to get it working with a domain account instead of a local account, this in turn very much pleased the SQL admins.  So it is possible to get it working with a domain account, but a local account *is* easier, and if you are a software developer, you may need an IT admin to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been perplexed by this before as well, and tried everything else mentioned in all previous replies, to no avail. In my case, I was trying to use a local user that I created myself (for a developer machine), but my problem was that I had not unchecked the "User must change password at next logon" checkbox on the properties of the User in the Computer Management tool when creating the User. This is yet another scenario that can result in this very generic error message from IIS. Unchecking this fixed the issue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180529/689718) [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2463368/john) suggested to set the password through the command line. Since my application pool has spaces in the name, I got this error message:

Failed to process input: The parameter 'Sites'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057).

I was able to set the password with the following command:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "/section:applicationPools /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser" "/[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.userName:DOMAIN\USER_NAME" "/[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.password:PASSWORD"
```

Comment: on windows 10, i had to remove all the double quotes to get this command to work

Answer (score 0):

I bumped in to this problem but my solution was something different

I was using a VM and by default the VM created an administrator user but created it without a password.

I had to go out of IIS, in to user settings, add a password to my user and then back to IIS. I then entered the details accordingly and the whole thing worked :-)

I mistakingly thought I was creating a new user here for IIS - I don't believe that is the case you must use an existing user (as in a Windows user).

Answer (score 0):

For me it was in my haste to follow the instructions for creating a merge agent account for replication I had left "User must change password at next logon" ticked. Make sure that the user does't have this ticked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a gMSA service account you have to enter domani\account$, meaning add a dollar sign at the end of your username.

Answer (score -1):

Use Your Laptop Password it worked for me.