# IIS 10 application pool identity set as custom account as Service Account. It throws the specified password is invalid. Type a new password

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

On windows 10 : IIS 10 throws the error:

> "The specified password is invalid. Type a new password"

when application pool identity set as Custom service account.

There is a solution I found out:  I can Add to the administrators group that custom account and I was able to add the account without any problem, but  we have a requirement not to add the service account into the administrators group.

Is there any other way I can get rid of that error?

Comment: Are you sure the pass is right? Why not use a buil-in account like AppPoolIdentity or NETWORK SERVICE?

Comment: How to check pass is correct. We have all the applications running under particular service account and it is used only on intranet. I can't change into apppoolIdentity or network service. This is happening only on my local PC. I have to set it up to use a custom account before I deploy into development environment.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915094/what-type-of-password-i-have-to-give-to-set-the-custom-account-for-application-p/26180529#26180529